# Cronjob: Visit a webpage everyday

Tags: cron

sadly I'm not THAT into Raspberry Pi to answer it so myself. I googled, but i hadn't found something helpful..

Is there an option to let the RasPi "visit" a specific link (php) once a day to a special time?

Hope you guys can help me! Thank you on that point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a linux question, not a Raspberry Pi question. The answer would be the same in just about any version of linux or unix.

To add a cron job type

```
crontab -e
```

If you want more info on how to add a cron job, how to specify the times, etc, then you can google it or man it.

```
man cron
```

Your command will probably look like this:

```
wget http://webpageaddress/
```

if you want more info on wget you can type

```
man wget
```

You could also use curl.

```
curl http://webaddress
```

In general, you use curl if you are just looking to test the connection, and wget if you actually want to retrieve something.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I will have a look when I'm back from work; but looks like exactly what I was looking for!